# Google api nearbysearch how to filter data business_status

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-nearby, google-nearby-messages

**I have a some issued when get return data from Google api nearby search.**

1. I get result only 60 from Nearby search. Is it possible to get result greater than 60th?
2. There are some data show business_status of CLOSED_TEMPORARILY or CLOSED_PERMANENTLY.
   I want to get data only business_status=OPERATIONAL. How can I do because limit of result data is 60?

[Example Data result from Google API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxq0T.png)

Thank for all suggestion:-)